# Elasticsearch query with wildcards

Tags: elasticsearch

Use [their data](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/docs/src/test/resources/accounts.json?raw=true) on Elasticsearch tutorials as an example, the following uri search hits **9** records,

```
curl -XGET 'remotehost:9200/bank/_search?q=city:R*d&_source_include=city&pretty&pretty'
```

while the following reques body search hits **0** records,

```
curl -XGET 'remotehost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
 -d'{"query": {"wildcard": {"city": "R*d"} },
 "_source": ["city"]
}
'
```

But the two methods shoud be equivalent to each other. Any idea why this is happening? I use Elasticsearch 5.5.1 in docker.

Comment: Didn't my answer help you ?

Comment: @sunkuet02 It is helpful, thanks! But this makes the two search methods inconsistent with each other (intuitively). Do you know if there is anything I can do to the database, so that both methods don't require the "keyword", or both require the "keyword", maybe?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it, hope it helps. And don't forget to upvote and accept my answer, it it helps.

Comment: @sunkuet02 I appreciate your willing to help. But my question is "the two methods should be equivalent ...", why they are not. You answered how to make the 2nd query work. I will upvote your answer but I can't accept it at this point, unless it tells me why the URI and body search appear not equivalent.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can get your expected result by hitting the below command. This commands add an extra `.keyword` with your command in field `city`.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/bank/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"query": {"wildcard": {"city.keyword": "R*d"} }, "_source": ["city"]}'
```

**Reason of adding `.keyword`**

When you insert data to elasticsearch, you will notice a `.keyword` field and that field is `not_analyzed`. By default, the field you have inserted data, is standard analyzed and there is a multifield `.keyword` . If you create a field `city` with data, then it create a field `city` with standard analyzer and added a multifield `.keyword` which is `not_analyzed`.

In your case you need a `not_analyzed` field to query (as `wildcard` query). So, your query should be on  `city.keyword` field which is by default not_analyzed.

In the first case, you have hit a get request to `elasticsearch` with query parameter. Elasticsearch will automatically converted the query as like second format.

For reliable source, you can follow the [Official docs](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings)

> The `string` field has split into two new types: `text`, which should be
>   used for full-text search, and `keyword`, which should be used for
>   keyword search.
>
> To make things better, `Elasticsearch` decided to borrow an idea that
>   initially stemmed from `Logstash`: strings will now be mapped both as
>   `text` and `keyword` by default. For instance, if you index the
>   following simple document:

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

> Then the following dynamic mappings will be created:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "type" "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> As a consequence, it will both be possible to perform full-text search
>   on foo, and keyword search and aggregations using the `foo.keyword`
>   field.

Comment: Can you provide a source/reference on the comment that "Elasticsearch will automatically converted the" URI query to the body query with ".keyword"?

Comment: @Luke, Once I have read it. I will give you the link of it in few minutes

Comment: @Luke, would you please check the link : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html in the section `allow_leading_wildcard` I think you will find your answer on this official blog